# Upload Multiple (Parallel) Files to a Single Release

Tags: github, cmake, github-actions

I'm quite new to github actions. I already managed to build my C++ program using CMAKE for ubuntu-latest and windows-latest, now I'm having problems uploading it to a release.
I'm using a strategy matrix, so the different OS jobs run in parallel.

My goal is to upload build files to a single Release Tag in which each file will have a custom name based on OS platform.

ex.:

```sh
Release Tag: V0.2.0
      Files: main_0.2.0_windows.exe
             main_0.2.0_ubuntu
                      ...
             main_0.2.0_other-OS.ext
```

Can someone help me to do so? Below is my current workflow yml.

** I already managed to upload single files to single release tags for ubuntu-latest. For windows-latest I got an error saying that the file to upload is not found :( .

```yaml
name: CMake

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      trigger:
        required: false
        default: 'workflow_dispatcher'
  
env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
  VERSION: 0.2.0

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest, windows-latest ]
        python-version: ['2.7', '3.6']
  
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work equally
    # well on Windows or Mac.  You can convert this to a matrix build if you need
    # cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      
    - name: Upgrade pip & setuptools
      run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
      
    - name: Install matplotlib & numpy
      run: python -m pip install matplotlib numpy 
      
    - name: Copy numpy core to include folder
      run: python ${{github.workspace}}/cp-numpy-core.py
      
    - name: Configure CMake
      # Configure CMake in a 'build' subdirectory. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only required if you are using a single-configuration generator such as make.
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type
      run: cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
      
    - name: Build
      # Build your program with the given configuration
      run: cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}} --target main
      
    - name: Test
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      # Execute tests defined by the CMake configuration.  
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html for more detail
      run: ctest -C ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
      
    - name: Rename Ubuntu Files
      if: ${{ matrix.platform == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
      run: mv ${{github.workspace}}/build/main ${{github.workspace}}/build/main_${{ env.VERSION }}_${{ matrix.platform }}_${{ matrix.python-version }}
    
    - name: Rename Windows Files
      if: ${{ matrix.platform == 'windows-latest' }}
      run: Ren "${{github.workspace}}\build\${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}\main.exe" "${{github.workspace}}\build\${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}\main_${{ env.VERSION }}_${{ matrix.platform }}_${{ matrix.python-version }}.exe"
      
    - name: Upload Artifacts
    - uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
      with:
        repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        automatic_release_tag: "${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}${{ env.VERSION }}/${{ matrix.platform }}/Python${{ matrix.python-version }}"
        prerelease: true
        title: "${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }} V${{ env.VERSION }} - OS: ${{ matrix.platform }} - Python: ${{ matrix.python-version }}"
        files: |
          ${{github.workspace}}/build/main_${{ env.VERSION }}_${{ matrix.platform }}_${{ matrix.python-version }}
          ${{github.workspace}}\build\${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}\main_${{ env.VERSION }}_${{ matrix.platform }}_${{ matrix.python-version }}.exe
```

Best regards & Keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using [svenstaro/upload-release-action@2.2.1](https://github.com/svenstaro/upload-release-action), that allowed me to upload assets to releases. The only downside is that I had to implement a different step for windows and ubuntu.

workflow action:

```yaml
name: Build and Publish Pre Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      trigger:
        required: false
        default: 'workflow_dispatcher'
  
env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
  
jobs:
  build-source:
    # Environment where to build
    strategy:
      matrix:
        platform: [ ubuntu-latest, windows-latest ]
        python-version: ['2.7', '3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9' ]
    
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work equally
    # well on Windows or Mac.  You can convert this to a matrix build if you need
    # cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    
    steps:    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      
    - name: Upgrade Pip & Setuptools
      run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
      
    - name: Install Matplotlib & Numpy
      run: python -m pip install matplotlib numpy 
      
    - name: Copy Numpy Core to Include Folder
      run: python ${{github.workspace}}/cp-numpy-core.py
      
    - name: Configure CMake
      # Configure CMake in a 'build' subdirectory. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only required if you are using a single-configuration generator such as make.
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type
      run: cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
      
    - name: Build Source
      # Build your program with the given configuration
      run: cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}} --target main
      
    - name: Test Build
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      # Execute tests defined by the CMake configuration.  
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html for more detail
      run: ctest -C ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
    
    - name: Upload Files to a GitHub Release (Ubuntu)
      if: ${{ matrix.platform == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
      uses: svenstaro/upload-release-action@2.2.1
      with:
        repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        file: build/main
        asset_name: main-linux_amd64-python${{ matrix.python-version }}
        tag: latest
        overwrite: true
        prerelease: true
        body: "${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }} for ${{ matrix.platform }}"

    - name: Upload Files to a GitHub Release (Windows)
      if: ${{ matrix.platform == 'windows-latest' }}
      uses: svenstaro/upload-release-action@2.2.1
      with:
        repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        file: build\${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}\main.exe
        asset_name: main-windows_amd64-python${{ matrix.python-version }}.exe
        tag: latest
        overwrite: true
        prerelease: true
        body: "${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }} for ${{ matrix.platform }}"
```